# Group >70% similar MySQL TEXT field data using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, grouping, analytics

I have a TEXT filed in the MySQL table. it has sentence

Example

```
Hello AAAA, where is your dog BBBB
Hello PPPP, where is your dog QQQQ
Hello XXXX, where is your dog YYYY
I am fine. thanks
I am fine. thanks
where are you going?
Thank you very much
```

here
first 3 sentence has 5 same word out of 7. so it is (5/7)*100=72% similar

4th and 5th 100% similar

my question is.
using php i want to group in a table like this

```
sample_sentence_group                              count
Hello AAAA, where is your dog BBBB                 3
I am fine. thanks                                  2
where are you going?                               1
Thank you very much                                1
```

how can i do it?
the table has more than 100K record

Thanks

Comment: i didn't try but i thinking to do this way 1)read once by one 2) compare with previos group

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30952/matroom

Comment: thank you for your kink reply. what is the best way to compare % of 2 sentence

Comment: You could try to cut your sentence by word (using the space as separator). After that, you will have 2 array of word. You can then retrieve the union (`array_intersect`) and comparent the length of the union array with the initial length. This will give you something that can be traduced into a percentage